# Bash discards command line arguments when passing to another bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a big script (call it `test`) that, after stripping out the unrelated parts, comes down to just this using which I can explain my question:

```
#!/bin/bash

bash -c "$@"
```

This doesn't work as expected. E.g. `./test echo hi` executes the only the `echo` and the argument disappears!
Testing with various inputs I can see only `$1` is passed to `bash -c ...` and rest are discarded.

But if I use a variable like:

```
#!/bin/bash

cmd="$@"
bash -c "$cmd"
```

it works as expected for all inputs.

Questions:

1) I would like to understand why the double quotes don't "pass" the entire command line arguments to `bash -c ...`.    What am I missing here (that it works perfectly fine when using an intermediate variable)?

2) Why does bash discard the rest of the arguments (except `$1`) *without* any error messages?

For example:

```
bash -c "ls" -l -a hi hello blah
```

simply runs `echo` and `hi hello blah` doesn't result in any errors at all?

(If possible, please refer to the bash grammar where this behaviour is documented).

Comment: I'd also appreciate if anyone can suggest a better title for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) I would like to understand why the double quotes don't "pass" the entire command line arguments to bash -c .... What am I missing here (that it works perfectly fine when using an intermediate variable)?

From `info bash @`:

> `@`
>        (`$@`) Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands
>   to a separate word.  That is, `"$@"` is equivalent to `"$1" "$2" ...`.

Thus, `bash -c "$@"` is equivalent to `bash -c "$1" "$2" ...`. In the case of `./test echo hi` invocation, the expression is expanded to

```
bash -c "echo" "hi"
```

---

> 2) Why does bash discard the rest of the arguments (except $1) without any error messages?

Bash actually doesn't discard anything. From `man bash`:

> If the `-c` option is present, then commands are read from the first non-option argument `command_string`.  If there are arguments after the `command_string`, they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with `$0`.

Thus, for the command `bash -c "echo" "hi"`, Bash passes `"hi"` as `$0` for the `"echo"` script.

---

> `bash -c "ls" -l -a hi hello blah`
>
> simply runs echo and hi hello blah doesn't result in any errors at all?

According to the rules mentioned above, Bash executes `"ls"` script and passes the following positional parameters to this script:

- `$0`: `"-l"`
- `$1`: `"-a"`
- `$2`: `"hi"`
- `$3`: `"hello"`
- `$4`: `"blah"`

Thus, the command actually executes `ls`, and the positional parameters are *unused* in the script. You can use them by referencing to the positional parameters, e.g.:

```
$ set -x
$ bash -c "ls \$0 \$1 \$3" -l -a hi hello blah

+ bash -c 'ls $0 $1 $3' -l -a hi hello blah
ls: cannot access hello: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Re: the last part - "the positional parameters are unused in the script". `ls` is the ls command. If the rest of the arguments are passed to `ls` shouldn't that print `blah` not found etc?

Comment: @usr, it shouldn't. I've added a sample. `ls` is executed alone. The `-l`, `-a` etc. are simply stored in the `$0`, `$1`, etc. However, `ls` will be executed with those arguments, if you use them in the script, i.e. the string passed to `-c`: `bash -c "ls \$0 ..."`

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `$*` instead of `$@` to pass command line as string. `"$@"` expands to multiple quoted arguments and `"$*"` combines multiple arguments into a single argument.

```
#!/bin/bash

bash -c "$*"
```

Problem is with your `$@` it executes:

```
bash -c echo hi
```

But with `$*` it executes:

```
bash -c 'echo hi'
```

When you use:

```
cmd="$@"
```

and use: `bash -c "$cmd"` it does the same thing for you.

**Read:** [What is the difference between `“$@”` and `“$*”` in `Bash`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008695/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-bash)