# bash array syntax and loops, please explain

Tags: arrays, bash, quotes

I get confused on array syntax in bash. I typically use quotes to enclose strings to loop through, but tutorials typically use parentheses. For kicks I made 4 simple loops. The first two work as I expected by echoing each item in the array, the second two gave unexpected output.

Why does this happen?

LOOP #1

```
$ List="item1 item2 item3"
$ for f in $List; do echo ${f}; done
item1
item2
item3
```

LOOP #2

```
$ List=(item1 item2 item3)
$ for f in ${List[@]}; do echo ${f}; done
item1
item2
item3
```

LOOP #3

```
$ List="item1 item2 item3"
$ for f in ${List[@]}; do echo ${f}; done
item1
item2
item3
item2
item3
```

LOOP #4

```
$ List=(item1 item2 item3)
$ for f in $List; do echo ${f}; done
item1
```

Comment: *Always* quote `${List[@]}`, as otherwise there is no reason to use `@` instead of `*`.

Comment: The first and 3rd don't have any array involved *at all*. Unquoted string expansion != array.

Comment: ...also, you've got a bunch of quoting issues here; http://shellcheck.net/ will catch them automatically, and provide wiki links with explanations.

Comment: @Charles. I think your comments get at the crux of what I don't understand. If you could point me to resources that explain what you mean by "Unquoted string expansion != array" and "a bunch of quoting issues", I would appreciate it.

Comment: In light of haccks comment below I can now see that quotes don't work. I'm just not understanding the reason. (edit: sorry, I cant figure out how to get the formatting to work)
    $ LISTA="item1 item2 item3"
    $ printf '%s\n' ${LIST6[2]]}


    $ LISTB=(item1 item2 item3)
    $ printf '%s\n' ${LIST7[2]]}
    item3

Comment: @charles. I am crawling through the duplicate answers you have linked above. They are helpful, just challenging for the less experienced.

Comment: The key thing is that quotes change behavior *on expansion*, not just assignment. So, in `for f in $List`, because the `$List` isn't quoted, the expansion goes through string-splitting (on characters in IFS) and glob-expansion (doing things like replacing `*.txt` with a list of files in the current directory matching that pattern); this is actually one of the behaviors that's responsible for a very large number of the common misunderstandings given in [Bash Pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls).

Comment: ...the same thing is true when expanding an array. If you have `array=( "first item" "second item" )`, then `$array` becomes an equivalent to `"first" "item"` (if `IFS` is at its default value), whereas `"$array"` becomes `"first item"`, whereas `${array[*]}` becomes `"first" "item" "second" "item"`, whereas only `"${array[@]}"` expands to the correct/original/unmodified value of `"first item" "second item"`... keeping in mind that in all of the above the quotes are syntactic, not literal.

Comment: See [What is the difference between "$@" and "$*" in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008695/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-bash) for an on-point discussion

Answer (score 1):

> The first two work as I expected by echoing each item in the array, the second two gave unexpected output.

Your fourth loop is equivalent to `for f in ${List[0]}; do echo ${f}; done`. This is documented in `man bash`:

> Referencing an array variable without a subscript is equivalent to referencing the array with a subscript of 0.

Third loop works but is not printing the original array. Try:

```
List=(item1 item2 item3)     # Declares array List
printf '%s\n' "${List[@]}"
item1
item2
item3

List="item1 item2 item3"     # Overwrites first element of array... 
                             # ... equivalent to List[0]="item1 item2 item3"
printf '%s\n' "${List[@]}"
item1 item2 item3
item2
item3
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have replaced `echo` with `printf` and quoted the variable.

Comment: Yes I meant `List="item1 item2 item3"`, I've updated the answer.

Comment: (thumbs-up) re: answer-as-edited.

Answer (score 0):

First 3 snippets should work, but the problem with 3rd is that `List="item1 item2 item3"` will replace `item1` with `"item1 item2 item3"` and that's why you are getting the output

```
item1
item2
item3
item2
item3
```

Change the name of the variable and it will work

```
List2="item1 item2 item3"
```

In last snippet `$List` is used without index and this is same as referring to the content of the first element of the array `List`.

Comment: Ah. I didn't realize that was happening. If I had run #3 first I wouldn't have seen it, or learned it worked that way. Thanks.