# How to get all input inside quote into variable

Tags: string, bash, getopts

I want to insert into variable anything I send inside `"`.

For example:

`check.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
./b.sh -a "$@"
```

`b.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts ":a:b:c:" opt; do
  case ${opt} in
        a) A="$OPTARG"
;;
        b) B="$OPTARG"
;;
        c) C="$OPTARG"
;;
        :) echo "bla"
exit 1
;;
esac
done

echo "a: $A, b: $B, c: $C"
```

Run #1:
Desired result:

```
user@host $  ./check.sh -a asd -b "asd|asd -x y" -c asd
a: -a asd -b "asd|asd -x y" -c asd, b: ,c:
```

Actual result:

```
user@host $  ./check.sh -a asd -b "asd|asd -x y" -c asd
a: -a, b: , c:
```

Run #2:
Desired result:

```
user@host $ ./check_params.sh -a asd -b asd|asd -c asd
a: -a asd -b asd|asd -c asd, b: ,c:
```

Actual result:

```
user@host $ ./check_params.sh -a asd -b asd|asd -c asd
-bash: asd: command not found
```

Comment: check.sh is adding `-a` before the arg list it gets, so it's effectively running `./b.sh -a -a asd -b "asd|asd -x y" -c asd` -- and the doubled `-a` is causing lots of confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$*` instead of `$@`:

check.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
./b.sh -a "$*"
```

`"$*"` is a string representation of all positional parameters joined together with `$IFS` variable. Whereas `$@` expands into separate arguments.

Also note that in your 2nd example you need to use quote pipe character string:

```
./check.sh -a asd -b 'asd|asd' -c asd
```

[Check: What is the difference between “$@” and “$*” in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008695/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-bash)

Comment: What if I need `'` to be forwarded as well?

Comment: For example `./check.sh -a asd -b 'asd asd' -c asd` for that output should be: `a: -a asd -b 'asd asd' -c asd, b: ,c:`

Comment: You should just quote it: `./check.sh "-a asd -b 'asd asd' -c asd"`

Comment: I can't. `check.sh` actually represent lots of different scripts that sometime call other common script `b.sh`

Comment: Your question is about `How to get all input inside quote into variable` so solution is also for that. In Unix shell quoting is very critical and not correctly quoting can change outcome drastically.

Comment: That is correct, but the solution I need is for the `b.sh` script - not for calling `check.sh` as I can't handle input. Run #1 simulate that desire.

Comment: @Nir You might want to start by reading [Bash FAQ 050](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Unfortunately this is the case. I already started to look at options like `${*//asd asd/'asd asd'}` but it did not sort the issue as the destination script saw it as `'asd`